# grant all on uri from spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, apache-sentry

While running 
`hiveContext.sql("grant all on uri 'file:/path/to/file' to role 'public'");` with Spark 1.6.2 I'm getting following error: `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Hive authorization does not support the URI or SERVER objects`.

Is there any way to execute this query form spark? Should I add other privileges to current user before the query?

`Grant all on database` works perfectly.